# homomorphisms of Banach spaces as topological groups

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$  be real Banach spaces. Verify that

i) $B_1$ and $B_2$ with the topologies by their norms are topological groups

ii)  if $T:B_1 \to B_2$ is a continuous homomorphism of topological groups then $T$ is a  continuous linear transformation.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! In future you should try to use MathJax to format your question. I've edited this question to do this and you can click on "edited x ago" to see what I've typed to achieve this. You should also indicate what you've tried to solve the problem. For example, for (i) what are the things you need to check and what have you tried to check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is the same that proving the continuity of sum operation.

Hint for (2): prove that for all $r=p/q\in\Bbb Q$:
$$T(rx) = r T(x).$$

Particular case: [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: @user560109 If you are happy with this answer you should accept it by clicking on the tick to the left hand side of it so that this question will be marked as answered.